# Creating ASP.NET window for login button

Tags: asp.net, ajax

when you go to http://4shared.com and click on log in button it shows a small window under the button and you can fill that boxes.
I am new to `asp.net` and I do not know how I should do this for my website ? is it an `AJAX` technique ? if yes how should I add this effect to my sites ?
can I do it by `Ajax Control Toolkit` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery. Go through this awesome tutorial for beginners. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp 
 The trick is to show a `div` on click which is set to `display: none` as default.

Answer (score 1):

There are many plugins that could assist you in this task. For example if you are using jQuery you may take a look at the [`jQuery UI dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) which is just one of the many plugins that could be used to achieve that.

In this particular example AJAX is used to submit the credentials to the server and perform the necessary verifications.